# String index out of range error in program that generates password in Python

Tags: python

I was given an assignment in university to write a program that will create user's password using their name and surname( ex: name = 'John', surname = 'Smith' => password will be 'JSomhinth', but I get “IndexError: string index out of range” mistake.

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
surname = input("Enter your surname: ")
print("Your credentials are %s %s." %(name, surname))

length = int((len(name) + len(surname))/2)
password = []
x = 0
y = 0
if len(name)>len(surname):
    for i in range(0, length):
        for n in range(0, len(name)):
            password.append(name[x])
            x += 1
            break
        for m in range(0, len(surname)):
            password.append(surname[y])
            y += 1
            break
print(''.join(password))
```

Comment: If you use `name = 'John', surname = 'Smith'`, this code just prints the full name because `len('John') < len('Smith')`. It also works fine if I take name=Johnny and surname = Smith. I get the desired password without any error

Comment: I know :D I didn't get to elif part, where surname would be longer

Comment: I think you should just use `length = min(len(name), len(surname))`

Comment: Bazingaa, this code works with some names and doesn't work with others for some reasons. For example, with Daniiar Ivanov it's ok, but with Daniiar Smith there's an error

Comment: Unrelated sidenote: these are terrible passwords, you should **never** use them.

Comment: Sure :D This is just a university assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue` handling the unequal length case.

Using a list-comprehension:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

name = 'John'
surname = 'Smith'

print(''.join([x + y for x, y in zip_longest(name, surname, fillvalue='')]))
# JSomhinth
```

Or using `map`:

```
print(''.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(name, surname, fillvalue=''))))
# JSomhinth
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
if len(name)>len(surname):
    for i in range(0, length):
        for n in range(0, len(name)):
            password.append(name[x])
            x += 1
            break
        for m in range(0, len(surname)):
            password.append(surname[y])
            y += 1
            break
```

every time you go through the outer loop you will hit the inner loop on surname and increment `y`.
Since surname is shorter than name, eventually `y` will reach (len(name)+len(surname))/2 -1 which will make `surname[y]` call throw out of bounds exception if name is at least 2 chars longer than surname.

In unrelated note, there is no need for inner loops, since every time they will only run once, increment global var and break, so the following code would work too

```
if len(name)>len(surname):
    for i in range(0, length):
        password.append(name[x])
        x += 1
        if y < len(surname):
            password.append(surname[y])
        y += 1
```

Austin's answer is the cleanest way to go about this problem though.

Comment: You said, "Since surname is shorter than name, eventually y will reach (len(name)+len(surname))/2 -1 which will make surname[y] call throw out of bounds exception if name is at least 2 chars longer than surname.", but I don't understand why. I'm very new to python, so could you please try to explain it to me, if it's possible.

Comment: Bro, I finally understand why it works this way! Thank you very much! And debugger too :D